# Difference between Opera VPN and Opera Turbo

Tags: vpn, opera

This 2 features are looking so confusing.

What should i use to hide my network use from ISP or Router owner?

Answer (score 2):

These are two very different things. Turbo will attempt to increase the speed of internet access without additional security that a VPN will provide such as encryption.

From Opera's [own explanation](http://www.opera.com/turbo) of Turbo

> The pages you visit go through one of our servers. The server identifies pieces of the page that can be compressed. It shaves off image pixels and corrects video buffering. Then, it sends back these smaller-sized pieces to your device.

Whereas the [VPN service](http://help.opera.com/opera/Windows/2393/en/private.html#vpn) (Provided by SurfEasy) does the following:

> Normally, your browser connects directly to websites, allowing websites to identify your IP address and its approximate location. With VPN, you connect to websites via a VPN server. As a result, your apparent location changes to the location of the server.
>
> From the point-of-view of websites, your browser is now located in the country given by the virtual location.
>
> Because the connection from your browser to the VPN server is encrypted, even if the local network is not, VPN enhances your privacy on the local network. You can hide your browsing activities from other users of that network.